# Auto-deploy in eclipse stopped as soon as i pasted my own context.xml in META-INF folder

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am running a simple web application on Tomcat using eclipse,

Now i wanted to use JNDI to look-up for Datasource,

so in my Web app project in WebContent folder there was already a META-INF folder,
So i added one file context.xml to it , i.e. WebContent/META-INF/context.xml

it is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true" path="/">

<Resource   name="java/mydb"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="40"
            maxIdle="30"
            maxWait="1000"
            username="app"
            password="app"
            driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
            url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample">        
</Resource>
```

I am able to do JNDI look ups in Servlets successfully,

but the side effect is that the auto deploy has stoped.
Now i have to again restart me server.

Prior to the above change, whenever i used to save the servlet or any html, i was able to see the change in browser,

but after adding context.xml file in my project, the auto deploy has stopped working,

Please tell me where i am going wrong,

Whether adding context.xml in our web project is good practise or should i change the context.xml of tomcate.

Please tell me